# How can I install “Python Editor” on “Ubuntu Bash” in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install a "python editor" that I can use for the Python 2.7 installation I've done via Bash Ubuntu in "Windows 10".

I beleive that the trick is to get a connection between "windows 10" desktop and the bash Ubuntu environment.

Hope someone has solved this and can help.

More info about "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows":

http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: What is "python editor"?

Comment: According to that very article, "the Bash environment and Windows have access to the same files on your computer." So you should be able to use any Windows text editor. Or you could install a Linux text editor.

Comment: Thanks @kindall:.
So I could for example "Download eric6-6.1.10.zip" and install it but how do I connect it to the Bash Ubuntu envorinment?
Says "root@user:~#"

Comment: You don't need to "connect it". You save the files in a directory, navigate to that directory in bash, and use them in Python.

Comment: Well, you're going to have some issues with Eric if you want to run a Linux version of Python. The Linux version won't run on Windows because it uses a GUI and that's not supported. The Windows version won't let you debug apps running on the Linux side because, as noted in the article you linked, the Windows side can't launch Linux programs and vice versa. What are you actually trying to accomplish with this wacky setup? Why aren't you just using a Windows version of Python or a Ubuntu VM?

Comment: TensorFlow is not supported on Windows and i thought a virtualenv would slower things down. Will I not face a similair problem if I go for virtualenv, For example if I would like to save a txt-file in the virtualenv will I be able to "reach" that and use it from the "Win 10" environment?

Comment: I was suggesting a virtual Ubuntu machine like VirtualBox, not `virtualenv`. You can share folders between the VM and the native Windows, that's not an issue.

Comment: @kindall, in recent builds WSL can run Windows processes (it uses binfmt_misc to run PE executables) and standard I/O redirection to pipes and files now works across subsystems (i.e. file descriptors are mapped to File handles and vice versa). This really sets WSL apart from using a VM.

Comment: That's really interesting. Makes me wish I had Windows 10 on my work machine; it would make a lot of things easier.

Comment: @eryksun, does that mean that this can be solved in some way? I don't have so deep knowledge about what you wrote so I'm not sure if you answered my question with your explanations that "......standard I/O redirection to pipes and files now works across subsystems (i.e. file descriptors are mapped to File handles and vice versa)"? Should I not try to use VM?

Comment: There's a good overview and a video posted on the [WSL blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability). This update is available in Windows Insider build 14951 and later. Possibly this could work with a Windows IDE that allows the user to set the command line to run Python to something like `bash -c "python ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this "issue" as well. (I think) The problem is that the WSL(Windows subsystem for linux) has a different python interpreter than windows. 
So when you try to run the same file from the editor and the bash terminal you would actually use two different version of Python to run the program.

It seems there is work being done to [integrate the WSL and VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67) Which is I think a solution to your question.